# Why is the accuracy and f1 score of this model the same no matter what?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

After doing some data wrangling, I have some variables that are either categorical ones labeled 0 or 1, or numerical variables that have been normalized to have values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. Then here is where I define and run the model:

```
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=6, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Fit the model
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring="f1_macro")
print("\nF1 score: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

However, no matter which features I put into X, or how much of them, the F1 Score will always be 49.79%

EDIT: I've also tested with different optimizers, but the result is still the same

Comment: The question says accuracy and f1 are same? You have not shown accuracy in your code. Since this is a classification task, how many classes are there and are they equally balanced in your dataset. `KFold` will not do data stratification which may be necessary to maintain the ratio of classes in train and test data. Use [`StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) instead